# Subquery returns more than one row error, answers on here not working

Tags: sql, mysql, stored-procedures

I am running into a subquery error but the answers on here say to use an IN () or a Join, I have tried using both and am still getting the error. I want it to get the count for multiple users, and not count duplicates based on the property_id. If anyone can help me out here, I am putting the Id's for team members into a temp table with one column, I am saving a SELECT * to that table in a variable and using it in the IN expression. Here is my code. The error I am getting is "subquery returns more than 1 row". `p_membersList` is a JSON array of userId's

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp(
    memberId INT(10)
); 
WHILE `_index` < `length` DO
    INSERT INTO temp VALUES(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(`p_membersList`,CONCAT('$[',`_index`,']'))));
    SET `_index` = `_index` + 1;
END WHILE;
SET @result:=(SELECT * FROM temp);
-- Total Count According To Filter
SELECT @result AS 'result';
SELECT count(distinct property_id) AS 'totalCount'
FROM `property` AS `property`
INNER JOIN
    `user_additional_data` AS `uad` ON `uad`.`user_id` = `property`.`user_id`
WHERE `property`.`user_id` IN (@result)
    OR `property`.`property_id` IN (
        SELECT `pm`.`property_id` AS `propertyId`
        FROM `property_member` AS `pm`
        INNER JOIN
            `property` AS `p1` ON `p1`.`user_id` = `pm`.`user_id`
        WHERE `pm`.`user_id`  IN (@result)
        GROUP BY `pm`.`user_id`
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            -- `pm`.`property_id` AS `propertyId`
            `p2`.`property_id` AS `propertyId`
        FROM `property_member` AS `pm`
        INNER JOIN
            `property` AS `p2` ON `p2`.`user_id` = `pm`.`user_id`
        WHERE `pm`.`created_by` IN (@result)
        GROUP BY `pm`.`user_id`
        UNION ALL
        SELECT `pm`.`property_id` AS `propertyId`
        FROM `property_member` AS `pm`
        WHERE `pm`.`created_by` IN (@result)
           OR `pm`.`user_id` IN (@result)
        GROUP BY `pm`.`user_id`)
  -- AND `property`.`is_draft` = '0'AND `property`.`is_active` = '1'AND `property`.`is_deleted` = '0';
  AND IF(p_filter1 = '1', (`property`.`is_active` = '1' AND `property`.`is_draft` = '0'
    AND `property`.`is_deleted` = '0'
    ), IF(p_filter1 = '2', (`property`.`is_draft` = '1' AND `property`.`is_active` = '0'
    AND `property`.`is_deleted` = '0'
    ), IF(p_filter1 = '3', (`property`.`is_active` = '0' AND `property`.`is_draft` = '0'
    AND `property`.`is_deleted` = '0'
    ), IF(p_filter1 = '4', ((`property`.`is_active` = '1' OR `property`.`is_draft` = '1')
    AND `property`.`is_deleted` = '0'
    ), ""))))
  AND (
            `uad`.`is_primary_owner` = '0'
        OR
            (`uad`.`is_primary_owner` <> '0' AND created_by IN (@result))
        OR
            (`uad`.`is_primary_owner` <> '0' AND created_by = `uad`.`primary_owner`)
        OR
            (`uad`.`is_primary_owner` = '1' AND `uad`.is_enterprise_code = '1')
    );
```

Comment: that is not mysql code alone `SET @result:=(SELECT * FROM temp);` can not work, when temp has more than 1 row

Comment: it is mysql, not sure if @result was storing anything from that, but I am not getting a syntax error. It just gives me the error listed above. Sorry MySql noob here.

Comment: please add all tables with data as create table and INSERT INTO abd how you call your procedure, so it is ompossible to debug it

Comment: also a ddl in mysql has no while, it is valid only in procedures

Comment: yeah this is in a stored procedure, sorry if I tagged it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set a variable to multiple values, so

```
SET @result:=(SELECT * FROM temp);
```

won't work. Just join with the `temp` table instead of using `IN (@result)`.

```
        SELECT `pm`.`property_id` AS `propertyId`
        FROM `property_member` AS `pm`
        INNER JOIN
            `property` AS `p1` ON `p1`.`user_id` = `pm`.`user_id`
        INNER JOIN temp ON pm.user_id = temp.memberId
        GROUP BY `pm`.`user_id`
```

Comment: gotcha makes sense, I did try to join, but let me try again. I did the join in the very beginning though, before the select from property_member. Should I just do the join where you have it?

Comment: That was just one example. You have similar code in all the queries in the UNION, you have to repeat it in all places.

Comment: BTW, if you're using MySQL 8.x you can use `JSON_TABLE()` to convert a JSON array to a table, instead of the loop.

Comment: Yeah I came across that approach unfortunately this database is running on MySql 5 something, that approach looked the easiest.

Comment: so do I no longer need the WHERE clause if I do a join?

Comment: normally a react guy, but we seem to be spread pretty thin atm

Comment: No, the join takes the place of `WHERE column IN (...)`

Comment: oh, Awesome thank you. Going to mark this as complete.

Comment: Thanks for not just yelling at me like some people on here lol